# How to restrict the number of inputs and turn int into lists Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, random, split

I am trying to restrict the user input for the lottery tickets to seven characters and for it to only accept integers, when I use the int(input) it gives me a ValueError. When I remove the int before the input it works fine. I then go onto change the input into a list by using split method. How do I restrict the inputs?

```
import random

number_choice = int(input("Input 7 lottery numbers between 1 and 100"))    
lottery_ticket = number_choice.split()          
print(type(lottery_ticket))        
random_nums = random.sample(range(1, 100), 7)  # generate a list of random numbers
print(lottery_ticket)
print(random_nums)
matches = set(lottery_ticket).intersection(random_nums)  # set.intersection matches the elements that are similar
print("The matching numbers are", matches)     


def matchingNumber():
    countMatches = sum(i in random_nums for i in lottery_ticket)
    print(countMatches)
    if countMatches == 2:
        print("You have won £5")
    elif countMatches == 3:
        print("you have won £20")
    elif countMatches == 4:
        print("you have won £40")
    elif countMatches == 5:
        print("you have won £100")
    elif countMatches == 6:
        print("you have won £10,000")
    elif countMatches == 7:
        print("you have won £1000000")
    else:
        print("You have won nothing!")


matchingNumber()
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample input it's supposed to handle?

Comment: You converted your input to an integer with `int`, then you tried to run `.split` on that integer but integers can't be split.

Comment: The input would be any 7 numbers, between 1 and 100. for example number_choice = "3, 45, 33, 7, 3, 90, 49"

Answer (score 0):

As Pranav pointed out, you are trying to apply a method (split) on an incompatible type (integer). Try this instead, it first reads in the numbers as a string, then converts them to integers. Next, it will check to see if exactly 7 numbers were given - if not it will exit the program. It assumes you will type input in the format `3, 45, 33, 7, 3, 90, 49` into the console.

```
import random

number_choice = input("Input 7 lottery numbers between 1 and 100\n")    
lottery_ticket_strings = number_choice.split(', ')
if len(lottery_ticket_strings) != 7:
    print("You did not input 7 lottery numbers!")
    exit(0)
lottery_ticket = [int(s) for s in lottery_ticket_strings]          
print(type(lottery_ticket))        
random_nums = random.sample(range(1, 100), 7)  # generate a list of random numbers
print(lottery_ticket)
print(random_nums)
matches = set(lottery_ticket).intersection(random_nums)  # set.intersection matches the elements that are similar
print("The matching numbers are", matches)     


def matchingNumber():
    countMatches = sum(i in random_nums for i in lottery_ticket)
    print(countMatches)
    if countMatches == 2:
        print("You have won £5")
    elif countMatches == 3:
        print("you have won £20")
    elif countMatches == 4:
        print("you have won £40")
    elif countMatches == 5:
        print("you have won £100")
    elif countMatches == 6:
        print("you have won £10,000")
    elif countMatches == 7:
        print("you have won £1000000")
    else:
        print("You have won nothing!")


matchingNumber()
```